# conditional replacement maven

Tags: java, maven, replace, conditional-statements

I used to replace the log level in my log4j.properties file from "DEBUG" to "WARN", when compiling my artifacts using the com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>replace</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <file>${project.build.outputDirectory}/com/myCompany/MyApp/app/log4j.properties</file>
            <replacements>
                <replacement>
                    <token>DEBUG</token>
                    <value>WARN</value>
                </replacement>
            </replacements>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

What I now want to do is replace the log level depending on whether the artifact is a RELEASE or a SNAPSHOT. Something like "if ${version} ends with RELEASE replace, else keep DEBUG level.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I thought about putting the keyword "SNAPSHOT" / "RELEASE" in a property, append it to my version number. This would give me the ability to check the property  a little something like this: [ant task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805258). But somehow I don´t really want to get into ant so much neither get some more plugins for such a 'little' task.

Comment: @Wingiw your question is not clear can you please describe it clearly .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Edited my original question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The `maven-release-plugin` enables the `release-profile` profile [by default](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#useReleaseProfile). Therefore, you can disable the execution of `maven-replacer-plugin` in that profile.

Maven's [introduction to profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in case you're not familiar with how profiles work.

Of couse, if you're not using the `maven-release-plugin` or don't like this solution, you could set up a custom profile doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will investigate your solution a little and accept your answer if I get it working.